# Query to element criteria

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, queries

Is it possible to turn a query into an element criteria model? Currently I'm doing this:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria('Conference_Session');
$criteria->conferenceId = $conferenceModel->id;

$query = craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($criteria);
$query->order("conference_session.cs_start_time ASC");

$queryResult = $query->queryAll();
```

I would prefer to be able to be able to add my MySQL commands then turn it back into a element criteria. I don't **have** to do this but I want to know if I could.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to have the same result as with an ElementCriteriaModel, instead of getting an ElementCriteriaModel.

What you want to do is mimic `craft()->elements->findElements()`, and put your own `$query` in it. This will more or less put the results in their models. You can just copy this function and replace the second line (where `$query` is defined) with your logics.

You could also do something like `Conference_SessionModel::populateModels($queryResult)`, but by the way Craft joins the content table in findElements this would be rather slow, as it would make a new query for every content field.

What would be really nice is if you could specify `$query` in findElements, too bad Craft doesn't support this (yet?)